# Can Ubuntu run on Intel's NUC devices?

Tags: performance, thunderbolt

I was wondering if anyone has experience running Ubuntu (or any other Linux) on [Intel's NUC computers](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/motherboards/desktop-motherboards/next-unit-computing-introduction.html)?

I was not able to find any reports on linux running on this device, only windows 7/8.

**Update:**
And what about Thunderbolt support in Ubuntu/Linux? I have found some posts form May2012 mentioning problems. So, what is the state with Thunderbolt nowdays?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since, Intel's NUC devices basically uses Intel core i3 processors, which are well supported by Linux and Ubuntu, Ubuntu should be Ok on these devices. Also, note that there is nothing special in Windows to be eligible for running on an architecture, where Ubuntu can't.

- [Specification details of an NUC computer](http://ark.intel.com/products/68308/Next-Unit-of-Computing-Board-D33217CK)

Here is also an article saying the same thing

> Microsoft's Windows 7 and Windows 8 is supported as is the Ubuntu Linux distribution meaning most users are catered for. - [source](http://www.itpro.co.uk/644617/intel-next-unit-of-computing-nuc-review/3)

Comment: OK, at least you found a site mentioning Ubuntu Linux. I did not. Anyway, maybe there is someone who can report of succesful Ubuntu experience on NUC?

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu 12.04 runs fine on NUC, except for that it complains low battary. I know, there is no battery in the unit.

Answer (score 0):

I have ubuntu 13.10 updated with kernel 3.12.0 running on my NUC and Thunderbolt works perfectly with Caldigit Thunderbolt station, which gives me USB3/Eth/Audio/HDMI functionality without the needs to install any drivers. The true plug-and-play!

Answer (score 0):

Currently running 13.04 on an Intel DC3217IYE with 4gb ram and an mSATA internal 64gb SSD. Runs like lightning and so far every peripheral I plug in runs correctly immediately, inc. Edimax USB dongle and a Gigabit USB to ethernet adapter. Running with 4gb ram and an mSATA internal 64gb SSD. Boots in under 20 seconds.